# Is there a way to show R2(s + 1, t + 1) > s · t .

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Is there a way to show R<sub>2</sub>(s + 1, t + 1) > s · t ?

The only way I know finding ramsey numbers to by graphing. But to prove the above inequality, what would be the best method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relation between Ramsey Numbers: $R(s, t) &gt; (t-1)(s-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3844066/relation-between-ramsey-numbers-rs-t-t-1s-1)

Answer (score 0):

Given a set of size $s\cdot t$, partition it into $s$ blocks of $t$ elements each. Then color the 2-element subsets by making a pair red if it's included in one block and blue otherwise.

For this coloring, any red-homogeneous set is included in a single block and therefore has at most $t$ elements. Any blue-homogeneous set has at most one element per block and therefore has at most $s$ elements.

Comment: thank you. Could you please explain more detail? I dont really get it... Thanks!

Comment: I've added details.